# VF RemoteAction not working after adding publisher action

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting, publisher

I have a VF page where remote action javascript and  record chatter enabled.  In chatter we have added publisher action using VF page. When I keep  both VF Remote and publisher actions together in page  remote action error is happening called classname not found.  If I remove the publisher action from page layout then the remote action is working fine.  Anybody face this issue before? Is it a salesforce bug?

VF code

```
 <apex:page id="pg"  standardController="Decision__c" docType="html-5.0" extensions="DecisionView" title="Finger Tip" tabStyle="Decision__c">
 <chatter:feedWithFollowers  entityId="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}" id="chatter"/>   
  <a href="" onclick="test1()">Click</a>
  <script>
        function test1(){ DecisionView.Test(function(result,event){alert(2)})}

  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
 public class DecisionView{

   @remoteAction
    public static void Test(){
    }
  }
```

Comment: could you post some code ?

Comment: Posted the code in siple form

Comment: change your controller and method scope to global.

Comment: I did but its not resolved

Comment: Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(  '{!$RemoteAction.DecisionView.Test}',function(result,event){alert(2)} );   is working